# Possible to remove/replace code in entire solution

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, ide, legacy-code

I have multiple lines of code in my solution that I'd like to remove.

They are, in this particular scenario:

`System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine([STRING]);`

I could've done a 'Replace All' on `System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine` but, obviously, I want to remove the entire thing (including the string parameter passed into the method) - I want the whole line of code to be deleted wherever a call to this method is made.

Is there a way in which I can do this (any way to provide a wildcard included in the replace criteria maybe?). Also, could I do this with comments/todo's too?

I appreciate this may seem bad practice to have to get to this point but would, for now, appreciate answers that are only on topic as opposed to answers that try and propose ways of preventing this in the future (which I've already acknowledged).

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Regular Expression in Visual Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2k3te2cs.aspx) Find and Replace dialog, use:

```
Find: ^[ \t]*(System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine\(.*\)\;).*\n
Replace:
```

That's will delete the entire line.

Comment: End of line is `$`. :)

Comment: @LucMorin you're right, i just tested and with `$` it keep the line.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use the Regular Expression option in the Replace dialog, and something like this should do:

```
System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine\("\w*"\);
```

Cheers

EDIT: Obviously, if you are passing variables to WriteLine, just remove the quotes:

```
System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine\(\w*\);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you mean to remove *all* instances of `System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine` then you could do the following:

1. Go to `Replace in Files` dialog box
2. Enter `System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine.*` in the `find what` box
3. Leave the `Replace with` box empty
4. Choose `Entire Solution` for `Look in`
5. Expand `Find Options` and tick `Use` and ensure `Regular Expressions` is shown.